# PAYPAL Identity API don't send account_type attribute

Tags: paypal, oauth-2.0, passport.js, paypal-rest-sdk

I have registered a new app in PayPal sandbox and give permission to get account_type
[Paypal app permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKWyr.png)

I do the next curl request

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token/userinfo?schema=openid \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer {my_access_token}"
```

And I don't receive any account attributes in response:
The fields that I have received:

```
{
    "user_id": "https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/identity/user/i-78126398172639182kjhgadkgdsk",
    "name": "Ivan Ivanov",
    "middle_name": "",
    "email": "mi****@gmail.com",
    "verified": "false",
    "birthday": "11111111",
    "locale": "en_US",
    "payer_id": "5555ddddd",
    "address": {
        "postal_code": "111111",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "AL",
        "street1": "NNNN",
        "street2": "",
        "city": "NNN"
    },
    "language": "en_US",
    "verified_account": "false",
    "birthdate": "1111111",
    "email_verified": "false"
}
```

What I do wrong? Or PayPal REST SDK has some issue with it?

Thanks

Comment: I assume that you have a properly generated `{my_access_token}` correct?

Comment: Shure! After oauth2 connection with appropriate scopes (openid profile email https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes) according https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/attributes/
I get accessToken.

Comment: Paypal remove account_type from the account attributes. Closed.